# Mixing ordinary and httponly cookies

Tags: php, cookies, httponly

I am using PHP `setcookie` to set ordinary cookies, then later setting one with httponly. It seems this does not work. The `setcookie` function returns success but the cookie is not set in `$_COOKIE`.

Is it possible to mix ordinary and httponly cookies?

UPDATE

Yes, it works.

Thanks Rudi.

Comment: Are you checking after a refresh/new page? Remember `$_COOKIE` doesn't get updated until the next request.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what to suggest, it works fine: http://rudiv.se/stack/cookie.php

Comment: Thankyou. My problem was in the domain parameter, not the httponly. I'll see if I can close this question.

Comment: Glad it's sorted for you :) It's still a somewhat good fit for Q&A if somebody were to be wondering the same thing, so probably best to leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, mixing non-httponly and httponly cookies is not a problem at all if you're reading them by PHP, because PHP obviously needs a HTTP request to be processed and so will receive the cookie as usual, regardless of it's `HttpOnly` flag.

The following test case can prove this (open, and refresh):

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump($_COOKIE); 
echo '</pre>'; 

setcookie('TestNonHttpOnly', 'True', time() + 3600, '/', '.example.com', false, false); 
setcookie('TestHttpOnly', 'True', time() + 3600, '/', '.example.com', false, true);
```

([Live test available](http://rudiv.se/stack/cookie.php))